# how to fix bricked ascend P6 with new firmware

Tags: huawei

I have a Huawei P6 ascend that currently will not boot to android. The splash screen will come up and the huawei red rose stays pulsating forever - this is apparently after huawei forced an unwanted software upgrade (since I didn't initiate any upgrade).

When I hold vol +- and reboot I get to the 'bios' or rom update mode (whatever the real name of this mode might be).  So reading some forum entries I put a file 'update.app' from [here](http://consumer.huawei.com/en/mobile-phones/support/downloads/p6-u06-en.htm) on a sdcard (both zipped, and unzipped in a folder 'dload' as well as at the root of the sdcard.)

Upon booting into rom-update mode however I never seem to get a successful reflash.

The system says:

ro.build.version =4.42

ro.product.name=UEDGE

Current build version release is not 4.2, don't need move/

Warning:battery percent is less than 15

Huawei USB update fail....

cust copying files...

copy cust files successed!

ensure_path_remounted_rw Failed

and i get a dead robot

FAIL

LOW BAT

fooling with various options that I get to after a while (like wipe data etc) doesn't seem to help so far.  Any clues?

I am now also trying (again) the options

wipe data factory reset

wipe cache partition

after doing those and trying again to install /sdcard/dload I get

E: failed to seek in /tmp/sideload/package.zip (invalid argument)

E: signature verification failed

formatting /cache

installation aborted

cust copying files

copy cust file successed!

Comment: Did u solve your problem ? I got the same ...

Comment: nope, sorry     I didn't manage to fix it and got a nexus5 instead